# Optimistic and pessimistic locking in Node/Postgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, optimistic-locking, pessimistic-locking

I'm planning to use Node for my next project, because it seems to be a good fit for the problem I'm solving.

One thing I need to figure out is optimistic and pessimistic locking. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#locking-records-for-update

Say, the user has a balance of 1. Two Node instances make requests concurrently to withdraw 1.  The two requests could pass the check of sufficient balance at the same time, thus making two successful withdrawals resulting in a balance of -1.

Rails provides a wrapper around Postgres transactional and locking features. Does some kind of similar wrapper exist for Node?

How do you solve this in Node/Postgresql?

I know this is a database feature, but I wonder if Node or some library provides a abstraction away from writing raw SQL queries?

Comment: I just came across the following link and thought of your question, though it might not have anything whatsoever to do with what you are after. https://github.com/commandprompt/postgres-js

Comment: It's definitely **not** a feature of Node as it has no functionality related to databases.

Comment: Ok, so for everyone looking for an answer to a similar question about optimistic locks in 2022 with knex.js (kinda tip, not exactly a solution, as it's only a character-limited comment).
You can use transactions and then, at the beginning of it, check the version of the queried data with forUpdate() function. It locks the queried row for the time of the current transaction. Then, manually update the version number and do whatever else you want with acquired data. Haven't found anything easier (afaik Spring has a utility to check the version automatically).